# PANDAS Web Scraping Multiple Pages

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was working on scraping data using Beautiful soup on multiple pages for the following given website and was able to do it. Can I scrape data for multiple pages using Pandas. Following is the code to scrape a single page and the URL has link to other pages as http://www.example.org/whats-on/calendar?page=3 .

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://www.example.org/whats-on/calendar?page=3'
dframe = pd.read_html(url,header=0)
dframe[0]
dframe[0].to_csv('out.csv')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply loop over the range of numbers and append to a list of dataframes. Afterwards, concatenate to one large file. One issue too of your current code is `header=0` is the default first row. However, pages do not have column headers. Hence, use `header=None` and then rename columns.

Below scrapes pages 0 - 3. Extend the loop limit for the other pages.

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = []

# PAGES 0 - 3 SCRAPE
url = 'http://www.lapl.org/whats-on/calendar?page={}'
for i in range(4):    
    dframe = pd.read_html(url.format(i), header=None)[0]\
                         .rename(columns={0:'Date', 1:'Topic', 2:'Location',
                                          3:'People', 4:'Category'})           
    dfs.append(dframe)

finaldf = pd.concat(dfs)              
finaldf.to_csv('Output.csv')
```

**Output**

```
print(finaldf.head())
#                                    Date                                              Topic                                         Location                             People                     Category
#  0  Thu, Nov 09, 201710:00am to 12:30pm  California Healthier Living : A Chronic Diseas...                West Los Angeles Regional Library                            Seniors                       Health
#  1  Thu, Nov 09, 201710:00am to 11:30am  Introduction to Microsoft WordLearn the basics...  North Hollywood Amelia Earhart Regional Library       Adults, Job Seekers, Seniors               Computer Class
#  2             Thu, Nov 09, 201711:00am                     Board of Library Commissioners                                  Central Library                             Adults                      Meeting
#  3   Thu, Nov 09, 201712:00pm to 1:00pm  Tech TryOutCentral Library LobbyDid you know t...                                  Central Library                      Adults, Teens               Computer Class
#  4   Thu, Nov 09, 201712:00pm to 1:30pm  Taller de Tejido/ Crochet WorkshopLearn how to...                 Benjamin Franklin Branch Library  Adults, Seniors, Spanish Speakers  Arts and Crafts, En Español
```

Comment: That was really helpful. I will try to explore more things on pandas. Looks fun. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. Indeed it is fun. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Below code will loop through the pages given in the range below and append to the dataframe with the selected fields.

```
def get_from_website():
    Sample = pd.DataFrame()
    for num in range(1,6):
        website = 'https://weburl/?page=' + str(num)
        datalist = pd.read_html(website)
        Sample= Sample.append(datalist[0])
    Sample.columns=['Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3', 'Field4', 'Field5', 'Field6', 'Time', 'Field7', 'Field8' ]
    return Sample
```